# Is there a General Implementation of the General Update Pattern

Tags: library, synchronization

The d3.js Library uses the General Update Pattern to describe a mutation of a HTML/SVG Tree by a data array using functions separating the entering, updating and exiting elements. (See [d3-selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join))

Is there any other implementation for the General Update Pattern describing an update for more general forms of state data like two arrays?

Something similar to this:

```
const state = [{id:1, data:"foo", data2:"foo"}, {id:2, data:"bar"}]
const change = [{id:1, data:"baz"}, {id:3, data:"qux"}]

const nextState = select(state, entry => entry.id)
    .update(change, entry => entry.id)
    .join(
        enter => enter,
        update => update,
        exit => {}
    )
    .each(function (d) {Object.assign(this, d)})
    .value()

console.log(nextState)
// [{id:1, data:"baz", data2:"foo"}, {id:3, data: "qux"}]


// Implementation sketch:
function select(state, keyF) {
    const stateMap = new Map()
    state.forEach(entry => stateMap.set(keyF(entry), entry))
    let changeMap = new Map()

    const selection = {
        update(change, keyF) {
            change.forEach(entry => changeMap.set(keyF(entry), entry))
            return selection
        },
        join(enterF, updateF, exitF) {
            // ...
            return selection
        },
        each(callback) {
            stateMap.forEach((current, key) => callback.call(current, changeMap.get(key), key, state))
            return selection
        },
        value() {
            return stateMap.values()
        }
    }
    return selection
}
```

Comment: Not realy familiar with that programming language, but isn´t it javascript?

Comment: Both the example and the d3 library are written in javascript, correct. I am not searching for a javascript library necessarily, although that would be useful. (By now I have implemented the pattern myself) My question is about ANY other implementation / library using that pattern.

Comment: But You would like to see how the pattern is implemented in that library, right?

Comment: Technically not part of the question but if I had the answer I'd include some relevant implementation excerpts to explain. (e.g. d3 relies on HTML Elements and stores it's data on them to reference later (hence the differences in my stub).)

Comment: So I was asking if you need aces to the code of the library.

Comment: If it's reasonably available, yes, that would be nice! But mentioning the library and showing it's API would already be sufficient for my use.